# How can I make a spectral plot in Excel?

Tags: excel, graph, plot

I have two columns of data - first is fractions (goes on x-axis), second is integers (goes on y).
Is there a way to plot one against the other in a histogram type manner so it looks like a spectrum?

Answer (score -1):

Use the "scatter plot" tool.  It is also called a "scatter chart" tool.  Once you have your chart in place, you can add a trend line to determine the formula for the relationship between x and y values. You will be able to find the formula in terms of y = mx+b.  You can also determine the r squared value which will be important in the interpretation of the relationship. There are several options for scatter charts that might lead you off course, so experiment with the tool a bit to discover the correct options for your situation.